# why is the log/root of a negative number "invalid" when it is possible to compute it?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Example:

$\ln(x^2+7x-6) - \ln(2x) = 0$

$x^2+7x-6=2x$

$x^2+5x-6=0$

$(x+6)(x-1)=0$

$x_1=-6$, $x_2=1$

Now, if I stopped here, I would only get half a point. That is because $0 < x$ and therefore $x_1=-6$ is invalid. $0 < x$ because you can't take the log of a negative number. Except you can. Okay, you get a complex number, it is hard to compute and above our level, but in this instance the final answer is just “$-6$”, so you dont even have to compute $\ln(2\cdot(-6))$. So why is the $x_1$ soltion invalid? $1/x$, $x=0$ is invalid, but that is not because it is a difficult problem, it is invalid because it enables contradictions. $\ln(-1)=x$ won't lead to contradictions even if you dont know what imagninary numbers are, just leave it like $\ln(-1)$ uncomputed. If we then got $e^x$ in a follow up question we could compute the whole thing as $-1$. Kinda like if we didn't have negative numbers, we could still simplify $2-4=x$ to $0-2=x$ and then if we got $3+x=a$ we could solve it like this:

$3+x=a$

$3+(0-2)=a$

$3+0-2=a$

$(3+0)-2=a$

$(3)-2=a$

$1=a$

According to the logic I am arguing this doesn't work because $0-2=y$ is invalid so you can't use $y$ in the first place.

So am I in the right for saying that $x_1=-6$ is a valid answer or am I missing something? Is there anything I stated wrong?

Comment: Your posts will be a lot more readable if you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format them.  Start by putting `$` signs around math expressions.

Answer (score 3):

There is a fundamental difference between negative numbers and logarithms of negative numbers, as far as equations are concerned.

A number has a *single* opposite (or negative): the opposite of $2$ is $-2$.

If you want to consider logarithms of negative numbers, you have to take care of the fact that the operation has not a unique result, but infinitely many.

So, writing $\operatorname{Log}$ for the logarithm in the complex numbers, the seemingly innocuous equation $\operatorname{Log}x=2$ has *infinitely many solutions*, namely all complex numbers of the form $e^2+2k\pi i$, for $k$ an integer.

Thus it's already a bit confusing to think about what's the meaning of $\operatorname{Log}x=\operatorname{Log}y$; not to mention that if we interpret $2\operatorname{Log}x$ as doubling every possible logarithm of $x$ and $\operatorname{Log}x+\operatorname{Log}y$ as adding every possible logarithm of $x$ with every possible logarithm of $y$, then
$$
2\operatorname{Log}x\ne\operatorname{Log}x+\operatorname{Log}x
$$

Don't use what you don't know about.

To make a different case, consider $S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n$. You don't know about series, but this seems to mean $1+2+4+\dotsb$, fairly simple. Then
$$
2S=2+4+8+\dotsb
$$
Look! If we add $1$ to both sides we get
$$
1+2S=1+2+4+8+\dotsb=S
$$
Uh, oh! This means $S=-1$.

The fact that you applying formal properties to objects doesn't mean the properties won't give contradictory results. You have to *prove* that no contradiction can arise.

By the way, the derivation above of $S=-1$ is perfectly fine if we interpret it in the [$2$-adic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number), but certainly not in the real numbers.

Or you can prove that, in the field of fractions of the ring of formal power series over the rational numbers,
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}
$$
but this doesn't mean you can substitute $x=2$ in that equality and “prove” that $S=2$, because substitution is not allowed in that field.

Answer (score 2):

It's a difference of solving the equation over $\mathbb{R}$ versus over $\mathbb{C}$. If you are asked to solve the equation over $\mathbb{R}$, then $x=-6$ is not a solution because the equation is not defined at $x=-6$ in $\mathbb{R}$. If you are asked to solve it over $\mathbb{C}$ then $x=-6$ is a valid solution because the equation is defined at $x=-6$ in $\mathbb{C}$.